# "More than two buffers in diff mode" - How do you turn off diff on the buffers?

Tags: vim, vimdiff

I did `:vert diffsplit file1.txt`, then realized I didn't want to diff it but a different file.  So I closed one window with `:q` and turned off the diff highlighting with `:diffoff`.

I then tried `:vert diffsplit file2.txt`, but now if I try to `dp` or `do` to put/get changes, I get the `E101: More than two buffers in diff mode, don't know which one to use` error.

How do I avoid this, or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should switch off diff mode for the unwanted buffer with `:diffoff` *before* quitting it with `:q`. Depending on your settings (e.g. `:set hidden`), the buffer will persist in the buffer list (`:ls`), and Vim will consider it when doing a diff.

A `:bufdo diffoff` should turn off diff for all existing buffers, though I usually just quit Vim and relaunch it with `vimdiff ...` should such a situation arise.

Comment: I sometimes to diffs within gvim with many other tabs open.  My normal solution for vimdiff was just to quit, but for gvim that's not ideal.  Thanks!

Comment: Before quitting any of the windows execute `:diffoff!` or `:diffo!` for short. This will turn diff mode for all the windows in the current tab page. See `:h :diffo`

Comment: I tried doing :diffoff! and it still did not work.  Had to do :buffo diffoff.  Once I did that, I found that the buffer in my left split was still in diff mode.  So on that buffer I did a :diffoff and then was able to do :diffthis in two other buffers successfully and make changes.

Answer (score 4):

Note the buffer number which you want to put/get the changes by `:ls` command.

Then prefix your put/get command with the buffer number of your choice, e.g. `2dp`.

Answer (score 3):

This may be kind of late reply but still for future feference

i do

```
:tabdo diffoff!
```